# Problem with detection of UIPopoverController class availability when running on iPhone simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, ios4, weak-linking

I work on an universal app that uses UIPopoverController for the iPad version. (Both the base SDK and the deployment targets are iOS 4.3)

When I use the iPhone simulator (version 4.3) to test conditional code paths for iPad and iPhone neither the weak linking nor the `NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController")` approach give the expected behavior.

When testing weak linking of the UIKit framework I make sure to user the LLVM 2.1 compiler and make the UIKit framework 'Optional' in 'Target->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries'. (As I understand is the way to do it in Xcode 4.1).

Running the code

```
if ([UIPopoverController class]) { 
...
_popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
...
}
```

on the iPhone simulator crashes the application indicating that the `[UIPopoverController class]` does not return `nil`. Replacing `[UIPopoverController class]` with `NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController")` above, results in the same crash.

Does anyone know how to go about to make these conditional checks work when running on the simulator?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try determining whether or not the code is running on an iPad.
If it does, you can safely use `UIPopoverController`.

```
- (BOOL)isPad
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)])
    {
        return ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    }
    else
    {
        return NO; // all iPad OS's implement -userInterfaceIdiom
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm sure your proposal works. However, wasn't the whole point of weak linking and testing of classes that you should only test for the functionality you're about to use and as such not assume on which (possibly future) devices the functionality is(will be) present. For this reason I'd really want to test for the functionality and not for device.

Answer (score 0):

UIPopoverController class exists as part of iOS starting version 3.2 so it should not return nil on any device with iOS version 4.x even iPhone, only iPhone with iOS 3.1.3 and below you get nil with weak(optional) linking. To determine wether you can use this class you try suggested above solution with userInterfaceIdiom.

Comment: Thanks for this clarifying point. In the end I used the method of testing for the UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad - and this works as I expect it to. I somehow got the impression from Apple's documentation that the best practice was to test for the class existence (and that in particular, the class UIPopoverController did not exist at all on an iPhone).